# Using a variable as object with values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that can accept a couple of parameters and one of those parameters can be an object with further properties inside. like this:

```
myFunction(res.columns, res.data, {
        margin: {
            top: 65
        },
        styles: {
            overflow: 'linebreak',
        },
        columnStyles: {
            1: {
                columnWidth: 100
            },
            2: {
                columnWidth: 80
            }
        }
}):
```

Now, my question is this:
You can see that "columnStyles" in there has different indexes and inside it has a property with its value. The thing is that depending on the type of request, the numbers 100 and 80 change. What i'm trying to do is a switch case that depending on the parameter you get, I assign a value to a variable like such:

```
switch (type) {
        case 'components':
            config = {
                1: {
                    columnWidth: 100
                },
                2: {
                    columnWidth: 80
                }
            }
            console.log(config);
            break;
    }
```

What I want to do is, that in "columnStyles", only put "config" and for it to take the values that were assigned in the switch case above, so it would be something like this:

```
myFunction(res.columns, res.data, {
            margin: {
                top: 65
            },
            styles: {
                overflow: 'linebreak',
            },
            columnStyles: {
                config
            }
    }):
```

What I'm seeing is that in the debugger console, "config"'s values are correct, but they are not being accepted and it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas or tips?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just set `columnStyles` to `config`?

```
myFunction(res.columns, res.data, {
        margin: {
            top: 65
        },
        styles: {
            overflow: 'linebreak',
        },
        columnStyles: config
}):
```

Unless, I'm missing something, the above should work for you.

If you want to *merge* in the `config` with other values, then you would use something like `Object.assign` or object spread (`...`).

To merge you might want to do this:

```
myFunction(res.columns, res.data, {
        margin: {
            top: 65
        },
        styles: {
            overflow: 'linebreak',
        },
        columnStyles: Object.assign(existingConfig, config)
}):
```

or

```
myFunction(res.columns, res.data, {
        margin: {
            top: 65
        },
        styles: {
            overflow: 'linebreak',
        },
        columnStyles: {
            3: {
                columnWidth: 123
            },
            4: {
                columnWidth: 678
            },
            ...config
        }
});
```

*note: the object spread syntax may not be available in some versions of node without some transpiling help :)

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
myFunction(res.columns, res.data, {
            margin: {
                top: 65
            },
            styles: {
                overflow: 'linebreak',
            },
            columnStyles: config, 
}):
```

and you should be good. Adding extra braces does add the object name as property:

```
{
                margin: {
                    top: 65
                },
                styles: {
                    overflow: 'linebreak',
                },
                columnStyles: {
                    config: {
                         columnStyles: {...}
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked great!